# Azure B2C - Password Rules Not Reflecting (Signup + Password Reset)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have implemented Azure B2C password complexity rules according to the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/password-complexity?pivots=b2c-custom-policy in a custom policy. I haven't changed any of their rules. All I get is the message *"One or more fields are filled out incorrectly. Please check your entries and try again"*. I expect it to complain about length and missing characters, which are numbers, special characters and uppercase characters. I have updated the layout versions to the latest. I have also disabled strong password as they have mentioned in the article. This does not seem to be validation on Signup and Password Reset flows. What am I missing?

**Update:**
If I inspect the script in the front end, I see the configured validation rules (predicates). I have also set the "HelpText" property of each predicate. I am still not winning.
[image]

More: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was actually a style that was implemented as part of the design on the landing page (unified Sign-In/Sign-Up). It basically hid the error messages that were displayed when validation was fired and there were results:

```html
#attributeList ul li.EmailBox label, #attributeList ul li.Password label, #attributeList ul li.TextBox label { display: none !important; }
```